# Connecting to localhost with Restsharp on Android

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, restsharp

I created a Web API and would like to access it in my Android XAMARIN App. It's a XAMARIN Forms App, which references a .NET Standard 2.0 library with the newest RestSharp nuget package installed.

Unfortunately I get the error:

> Error: ConnectFailure (No route to host)

whenever I do the following:

```
public async Task<List<ETFPortfolio>> GetPortfolios()
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://10.0.2.2:51262/api/");
    var request = new RestRequest("portfolio", Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    var response = client.Execute(request); // Result with the error stated above

    throw new Exception();
}
```

My WebAPI controller is set up like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PortfolioController : Controller
{
    // GET api/portfolio
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var handler = new MyHandler();
            var portfolioList = await handler.Handle();
            return Ok(portfolioList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I found a similar question, unfortunately there were no answers yet.
[Error: ConnectFailure (No route to host)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181653/error-connectfailure-no-route-to-host)

Is there anything I'm missing here or could check out to make this work?

Comment: Can you access http://10.0.2.2:51262/api/portfolio in the emulator's web browser?

Comment: I use my phone to debug. And no, actually I cant :(

Comment: If you use a real device then you cant access a localhost. Your API is running on a remote machine. So you need to use a proper ip address.

Comment: Ok, that is awkward. Youre absolutely right, I didn't think that through, always were using an emulator apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a real device, your API url should not be a `localhost` but an IP address of the computer on which you have the API running.

`localhost` will work only on the emulator running on the same machine with your API.

P.S.: I wrote a [blogpost](https://smellyc0de.wordpress.com/2018/03/03/how-to-access-localhost-from-android-emulator-and-ios-simulator/) on this topic, you might be interested in checking it as well.